# 404 error on REST Easy

Tags: php, rest, slim

I am new into building restful php applications and as such was trying something simple here is my php code

```
<?php

require '../Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/fname/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});
$app->run();

?>
```

The thing works fine if I load the url `http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/fname/Test` through the browser, and gives an output

> Hello, Test

However trying it out with REST Easy plugin provides this error

```
Status

404 Not Found

Headers
Name    Value   
Date    Wed, 05 Nov 2014 10:51:02 GMT
Server  Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.5.15
Content-Length  524
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html
```

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: what is the url that you have used in your REST Easy plugin ?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/fname

Comment: so you should try with this url : localhost:8080/rest/v1/fname/Test (exactly what you have used in your browser)

Comment: Am I not supposed to pass the parameters in REST Easy plugin by adding the values in it rather than appending it to the url?

Comment: Be careful: name is not a GET parameter but a part of the URL. Slim reads that part of the url like a variable, so you can do magic things.

Comment: I understand but please tell me if this code has any flaws, if not then why and how do you test it in REST Easy plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$app->get('/fname/:name', function ($name) {
```

This will match URLs like `/fname/test` and `/fname/foo`, but not `/fname?test=bar`

You used just the URL `/fname` in your REST plugin. You do not have a matching route for this. So to fix this, call either `/fname/test/` from your plugin or create a matching route.

GET parameters have a key and a value (`?foo=bar` will results in an array with a key `foo` and the value `bar`). So it would not make sense that your `:name` matches a GET parameter. What would it pick, the key or the value? And which, if there are multiple?